# How to emulate returning arbitrary values from shell functions?

Tags: shell, shell-script, command-line, function

Shell functions are just statements and they don't return values. Can anyone share best practice on writing functions that return values in bash?

Let's say I've a function that joins two strings:

```
JoinStrings() {
    returnValue="$1$2"
}
```

How do I reuse this function in my code? How do I get `returnValue` to be returned to caller? Should I just use it as a global after this function call? That leads to many errors with global variables everywhere... How to achieve code reuse in the shell?

Comment: well, if you don't use functions to set variables you dont have those kind of problems. if your function was some validation test on its arguments, and you did: `validStrings "$var1" "$var2" && newVar=$var1$var2` you might find it a lot easier to  get along.

Comment: `returnValue` is a global variable unless you use the keyword `local`.

Answer (score 3):

In Unix and GNU, the *standard output* of the function can be considered the return value.

Here's an example using shell command expansion `$(...)`:

```
JoinStrings() {
    echo "$1$2"
}

joined_strings=$(JoinStrings string1 string2)

echo string1 and string2 joined are $(JoinStrings string1 string2)
```

There is a shell `return` statement for use in functions, which sets the exit code (status code) of the command. The exit code is a small integer.